# Does html_entity_decode() allow for safe output?

Tags: php, xss, htmlpurifier

Working with the car sales website Autotrader and they do not output html symbols. Instead they don't allow the use symbols by converting them to their entities and only outputting that.

For some reason they don't seem to feel its necessary to decode the entities for output.

This leads me to another question about my own website.

I am using HTMLPurifier to safely save and output user input.

This converts all symbols and < etc to their entities.

What is the correct way to output html entities but as their proper symbols in PHP?

I have been using html_entity_decode() which works. But it has occurred to me that this might in fact literally change the characters back and there for allow XSS etc attacks again.

How can i PHP echo a string that contains entities but display the symbols correctly and safely?

Comment: Just send it to browser with the entities, browser will show them as the real characters - safely, as you call it.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not decode, send the string with entities directly to the HTML output.

The HTML entities will be shown correctly by the user's browser. When you output from PHP

```
echo "Hello kitty!&lt;script&gt;steal_her_password();&lt;/script&gt;";
```

then the user will correctly see

```
Hello kitty!<script>steal_her_password();</script>
```

but if you decode this string first, then the user will see only

```
Hello kitty!
```

plus her password will be stolen.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As a side note, if this is the case then why would Autotrader not show the correct characters on their website?

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a specific page where they do not show correct characters?

Comment: After searching for the entity i cannot find any examples, however there is still some issues where the pound symbol displays with an A in front of it. See here in the description http://www.autotrader.co.uk/classified/advert/201406305433495/sort/default/usedcars/onesearchad/used%2Cnearlynew%2Cnew/postcode/so195sp/keywords/%C3%82%C2%A3/radius/1500/page/1?logcode=p          Im guessing this is a problem with the character set they use.

Comment: some people do use pound signs correctly however. Is there anything i could do when listing adverts to make sure the pound sign is properly displayed?

Comment: What you see is a character encoding issue: utf-8 vs 1252. The page you pointed out does not specify any encoding, so it is rendered in a default encoding, which on Windows should be 1252. However, the character £ is encoded in utf-8, which accidentally corresponds to Â£ in 1252. If your input encoding is consistent and controlled by you, then you just need to be consistent in that your output encoding corresponds to the specified charset. And of course you need to specify a charset: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.